# <!DOCTYPE = HTML> works, <!DOCTYPE html> does not

Tags: html, doctype

I've put  at the top of my html files, which contain jquery, javascript and iframes and the pages load just fine. Changing it to the standard  and none of those things will load.

So far I've been going ahead with "= HTML," but it doesn't show up properly on Windows 7 browsers. Any idea what's going on, and how I can put a !DOCTYPE declaration in the pages that won't create this problem?

EDIT: The abbreviated code is here. The specific problem is with an iframe on the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE = HTML>
<HTML>
<body>
...
<iframe src="..." width="700" height="93"></iframe>
...
</body>
</HTML>
```

(this works)

```
<DOCTYPE = HTML>
<HTML>
<body>
...
<iframe src="..." width="700" height="93" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
...
</body>
</HTML>
```

(in this one the iframe doesn't load)

I'm testing this with Firefox 45.0.2 and Chrome 49.0.2623.112

Comment: Please post the full code for your HTML as part of your question. The correct declaration for HTML5 is `<!DOCTYPE html>`. And which browsers are you trying here? And what versions of each?

Comment: how are you trying to view the `<!DOCTYPE html>`?  the doctype is merely metadata for the page.  you should research [DTD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration).  you shouldn't ever see it appearing on the page.

Comment: Both of the declarations in the code posted above are wrong. The correct declaration is `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Use that and only that if you're developing HTML5 web pages/apps. See here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: ManoDestra said it! there is no such declaration as anything you have up there. But am I the only one reading this correctly? What developer/designer doesn't know how html5 DTD??? OMG

Comment: @ManoDestra <!DOCTYPE html> gives the same results as <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: frameborder and scrolling properties are not supported in HTML5. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp. Use CSS instead.

Comment: I've taken out the unsupported properties and changed it to <!DOCTYPE html>. The iframe doesn't load.

Comment: There must be something non standard regarding your iframe's source code then. Have you amended its doctype declaration to HTML5 also? Or is it still set to HTML4?

Comment: The src is not HTML5, but I've read elsewhere that an iframe should still load if the !DOCTYPEs don't match. EDIT: OK, I've matched them up, and it's still not loading.

Comment: I just did a basic test with an HTML5 outer document and an iframe containing an inner HTML4 document, with only its width and height properties set and it worked fine. Try changing the src of the iframe to a really simple test page, to see if you can get something to load in the iframe. Then, you'll have to add the content gradually from the one you really want to include to see which part of the iframe's content is making it fail to load. I'm also using Firefox 45.0.2 BTW, on Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: Any luck with this yet, Robert? I'm curious as to what is causing the failure with your iframe :)

Comment: @ManoDestra thanks for your concern - fixed the <!DOCTYPE> format and made sure I crossed my t's and dotted my lower case j's. It now works as intended.

Comment: Perhaps you could post the solution as answer, if you identified what was causing the issue?